# iOS: Property not found on object of type ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

so I'm trying to set a float value into another view controller, NewLinkViewController.

Here is my code:

```
    - (IBAction)selectSize:(id)sender {
UIButton *selectSize = (UIButton *) sender;
sizeChosen = [[[selectSize titleLabel] text] floatValue];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [mainController setMySizeLabel:sizeChosen];
    [NewLinkViewController.sizeChosen = sizeChosen];

}];
```

}

I'm getting this error: http://puu.sh/7WSA9.png (says "Property 'sizeChosen' not found on object of type 'NewLinkViewController'")

I clearly have the @property in my NewLinkViewController.h like this:

```
    @property float sizeChosen;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to set the property on the *class*, when what you should be doing is setting it on an *instance* of `NewLinkViewController`. You may need to pass that instance in to the view controller that is doing the "choosing." (Unless you really did name your instance variable using a capital letter, in which case I'm mistaken.)

Comment: Try: `@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat sizeChosen;`

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're setting a property on the class and not the object of the class `[NewLinkViewController.sizeChosen = sizeChosen];`

More over, if you use the dot syntax, you don't need the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your property like

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) float sizeChosen;
```

and set your sizeChosen property like below

```
  - (IBAction)selectSize:(id)sender {
      UIButton *selectSize = (UIButton *) sender;
      sizeChosen1 = [[[selectSize titleLabel] text] floatValue];
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [mainController setMySizeLabel:sizeChosen1];
        newLinkViewController.sizeChosen = sizeChosen1;//newLinkViewController should be the instance of NewLinkViewController 

     }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the float variable property with instance of class NewLinkViewController and also as rounak suggested no need to use square brackets when accessing the properties method.
Use like this below:-

```
  NewLinkViewController *newLinkVw=[[NewLinkViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourVwNibnm" bundle:nil];
 //now access your property
   newLinkVw.sizeChosen=sizeChosen;
```

Note:- Make sure before setting or accessing properties of class. Your class instance should exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
- (IBAction)selectSize:(id)sender {
UIButton *selectSize = (UIButton *) sender;
sizeChosen = [[[selectSize titleLabel] text] floatValue];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [mainController setMySizeLabel:sizeChosen];
    NewLinkViewController *newLinkController = [[NewLinkViewController alloc] init];
    newLinkController.sizeChosen = sizeChosen;

}];
```